# Sitecore Personalization - Change Sublayout parameters based on visitor profile

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms

Is there any way to set different parameters for a sublayout based on visitor profile. When I goto presentation details and click personalize I can only set different datasource or rendering for different conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create rules under /sitecore/system/Marketing Center/Personalization/Rules. To understand rules this could be a start point http://sdn.sitecore.net/reference/sitecore%206/rules%20engine%20cookbook.aspx
The diea, is that you create different rules, which will execute some actions when a set of conditions are satisfied.
Then, in the presentation detail of your control, you can chose which rules to apply.
In order to view the personalization section in the presentation details you need to go to: 
Sitecore => Control Panel => preferences => Change your application options => View tab => Third section "Control properties" and check the "Show the personalization section.

Comment: I can already see personalization section in the presentation details. What I am trying to achieve is set the sublayout parameters based on certain condition. i.e where the value of the specific profile key compares to specific value I want to set Sublayout parameter to "A" else "B"

Answer (score 2):

Very short story is; you can't. While you might be able to via the Rules Engine as Vincent suggests; a more common solution is to not have a component rely too much on component parameters.

Try looking into moving your parameter into the datasource template for the item itself. That way, whatever it is you need to control when personalising, becomes something you define on the content item itself. Semantically also more correct - parameters should not really be used for anything that would change in personalisation scenarios.

Comment: Agree that with personalisation you're basically forced to push it into the data source template, which really limits the usefulness of rendering parameters.